# How to use beautiful soup to output tags contents to CSV?

Tags: python, file, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to read in a text file which contains a set of tags "text". Is it possible to use beautiful soup to output the contents of selected tags to CSV?

SampleCode:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<os>Windows Vista or Windows 7</os><filename>AS_ENGINE.EXE</filename><header_size>240</header_size><atime>2019-04-28T13:34:34Z</atime><runs>1</runs><filenames><file>
<os>Windows Vista or Windows 7</os><filename>CHRMSTP.EXE</filename><header_size>240</header_size><atime>2019-04-28T13:15:32Z</atime><runs>2</runs><filenames>
<os>Windows Vista or Windows 7</os><filename>RUNDLL32.EXE</filename><header_size>240</header_size><atime>2019-04-28T13:07:35Z</atime><runs>1</runs><filenames><file>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")

for x in soup.find_all("runs"):
    print("Orginal ", x)

for x in soup.find_all("dir"):
    print("Orginal ", x)

for x in soup.find_all("filename"):
    print("Orginal ", x)
```

I then want to write certain tags to csv...

```
fieldnames = 'File Nmae','Number of runs','File Path'
with open("C:\\ProgramData\\processed\\winprefetch.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerows([[diskimage_name * row], filename, numberofruns,file]
```

Full Code:
This first section pulls the name of the disk this information came from

```
import os
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def regx():
    #Gets the disk name
    with open("C:\\ProgramData\\\processed\\diskimagename.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        raw = (str(file.readlines()))
        print(raw)
        diskimage = re.findall("[^\\\/:*?\"<>|\r\n]+$", raw)
        diskimage_edit1 = re.sub("\"", "", str(diskimage))
        diskimage_edit2 = re.sub("']", "", diskimage_edit1)
        diskimage_name = diskimage_edit2
        print(diskimage_name)
        file.close()
```

The next section pulls the "runs" tags and writes it to an array to be wrttien with CSV writer.

```
########################################################
    with open("C:\\ProgramData\\output\\winprefetch.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        print("defo working")
        text_raw = ("%s;" % "{;}".join([line.strip().replace("\t", ",") for line in file.readlines()]))
        text = re.sub("#.+\B \d.\d{;}", "", text_raw)
        arr_prefetch = [r.split(",") for r in [r for r in text.split("{;}")]]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")

        #[x.text for x in soup.find_all("runs")]

        for x in soup.find_all("runs"):
            print("Orginal ", x)
        for x in soup.find_all("runs"):
           arr_runs = [x]
         #   print(arr_runs)
        #for x in soup.find_all("dir"):
         #   arr_dir = [x]

        print("Domain: ", arr_prefetch)

    ##############################
    #Domain writing to csv
    fieldnames = 'Disk Name','Number of runs','File Path','Disk Location', 'FileName', 'Headers'
    with open("C:\\ProgramData\\output\\processed\\winprefetch.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)
        writer.writerows([[diskimage_name * row, ] for row in arr_prefetch])
        csvfile.close()
# #regx

if __name__=="__main__":
    regx()
```

I would love to be able to read in the tags and select which ones I want to write to CSV so for example i want the following output;

```
Filename    Dirc    runs
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
ETC ETC ETC
```

Comment: What do you get when you run the code?

Comment: What's your desired output? (if you could type out at least one row that would be great)

Comment: ^^Please show some expected output rows as mentioned above

Comment: @Fozoro I have updated the question above, thanks for your replies.

Comment: @QHarrI have updated the question above, thanks for your replies.